# Meaning of sentences talking about falling out of love

Tags: meaning, adverb-placement

> I don’t wanna wait another minute to find out whether you love me anymore

Which one does the above sentence mean? Or other meaning?
1)  I do ***not*** want to wait another minute ***anymore*** to find out whether you love me.
2)  I do not want to wait another minute to find out whether you love me or ***not anymore***.

Likewise:

> I’m not sure I love you anymore.

1)  I’m ***not*** sure ***anymore*** I love you.
2)  I’m not sure whether I love you or ***not anymore***.

Another one is:

> Oh! I long for Jeannie, and my heart bows low ***never more*** to find her where the bright waters flow

For the above example, can I say “my heart bows low to find her ***no (= never) more*** where the bright waters flow.”? (My guess is from the expression of “The army has arrived. We should fear ***no more***.”) (formal English)

And does this mean the following or other meaning?
1)  Oh! I long for Jeannie, and my heart bows low because “I (or *my heart*?) will find her no (= never) more where the bright waters flow.” (to find = future = will find)
2)  because “I (or *my heart*?)” have found her no (= never) more where the bright waters flow.” (to find = *recent happening* or result = *have found*)

Comment: The line about Jeannie is not about falling out of love, but rather about loving someone, but not being able to be with them.

Answer (score 2):

You are butchering at least one of the originals with your paraphrases.

Let's start with the easy one:

> I’m not sure I love you anymore.

This simply means:

> I used to love you; now, I'm unsure if I do.

The word *anymore* indicates the speaker once had love for this other person. The expression *not sure* indicates uncertainty about that love at the current time.

---

As for:

> I don’t wanna wait another minute to find out whether you love me anymore

The second part of that is essentially asking, "Do you love me anymore?" (or, put another way, "Do you still love me? Or is your love now gone?").

The first part is saying, "I don't want to wait any longer to find out. Please, tell me now.")

---

As for that last one, you should never send the users of ELL scrounging on the internet to find where you found something you want us to analyze! (Read [this meta question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source) to find out why.) You should have told us this is an [Al Jolson song lyric](https://www.lyrics.com/lyric/7029257/Al+Jolson/I+Dream+of+Jeannie+With+the+Light+Brown+Hair), and provided more context:

> Sighing like the night wind and sobbing like the rain
>    Wailing for the lost one that comes not again
>   Oh! I long for Jeannie, and my heart bows low
>    Never more to find her where the bright waters flow

First and foremost; that's poetic language, and you should know that nobody talks that way in conversation. As for the meaning, though, that's simple enough:

I am sad (*heart bowing low*) because I won't see (*find*) Jeannie near the river ever again.

The phrase *never more* is a poetic way of saying something won't happen again.